# How to configure SSL certificate with CNAME to a second website.

Tags: php, ssl, certificate, cpanel, cname

I have a client.mainwebsite.com that is on a system.clientwebsite.com.

My client bought SSL for *.clientwebsite.com.
I´ve tryed uploading the certificate on mainwebsite.com, on Cpanel, but it doesn´t work.

Any sugestions?

Comment: What error do you encounter?

Comment: This is not a programming question, it should be on serverfault.com.

Comment: No error, I uploaded the certificate PEM and CRT, and when I access https on my client side it doesn´t show my website.